# How to change the instance count of an ECS EC2-moded cluster?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

When you create a cluster, you declare an instance count and that number of EC2 instances are created. When you even tweak the entries in the associated security-group, ECS will re-fill all of its instances in order to adopt the security changes.

There appears to be no way to tweak the number of instances, which is a big deal since you'll need to dump all of your existing scheduled tasks and services in order to create (or delete and recreate) a cluster to have the updated count. I don't understand why this (or other settings, such a instance type) can't be modified since even tweaking security settings will already reprovision the cluster and this would ostensibly have a similar response.

Am I missing something?

[image: Instance count]